# How to sum BigDecimal as class variables

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bigdecimal

I have this class:

```
public class Period {
private BigDecimal periodAmount;

public BigDecimal getPeriodAmount() {
    return periodAmount;
}

public void setPeriodAmount(BigDecimal periodAmount) {
    this.periodAmount = periodAmount;
}
```

And I was testing this on Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);
    List<Period> periods = new ArrayList<Period>();

    Period periodOne = new Period();
    Period periodTwo = new Period();
    Period periodThree = new Period();
    Period periodFour = new Period();
    periodOne.setPeriodAmount(new BigDecimal(33564899.47));
    periodTwo.setPeriodAmount(new BigDecimal(22978517.87));
    periodThree.setPeriodAmount(new BigDecimal(19526899.32));
    periodOne.setPeriodAmount(new BigDecimal(18056899.98));

    periods.add(periodOne);
    periods.add(periodTwo);
    periods.add(periodThree);
    periods.add(periodFour);

    for(Period b : periods){
        total.add(b.getPeriodAmount());
    }
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

But it throws me a NullPointerException that I couldn't find the reason. I tried without a list, like this:

```
BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);
Period periodOne = new Period();
periodOne.setPeriodAmount(new BigDecimal(33564899.47));
total.add(periodOne.getPeriodAmount());
System.out.println(total);
```

And then I get the total printed as 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'But it throws me a NullPointerException' At which line? Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: Sorry. At the line total.add(b.getPeriodAmount());

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.math.BigDecimal.add(BigDecimal.java:1288)
 at br.adv.martinelli.comprovsis.model.Company.main(Company.java:71)

Comment: change `periodOne.setPeriodAmount(new BigDecimal(18056899.98))` to `periodFour.setPeriodAmount(new BigDecimal(18056899.98))`

Comment: Great! It worked. But now total shows up as equal to 0 again...

Comment: here you go : `total  = total.add(b.getPeriodAmount())`

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer. I thought the BigDecimal method .add would sum everything up.